# Implementing annotation based Spring AspectJ (JavaConfig)

Tags: java, spring, exception, aspectj, spring-aop

We're trying to implement AspectJ `@Aspect` into our existing software for executing some code after a service call is made.

**Note:**

- We have service interfaces and implementations being `@Autowired`
  throughout the project via rest controllers as well as other service implementations.
- This project is entirely a Java Configuration with no XML whatsoever.
- We're using Spring 4.1.2 RELEASE deployed on Tomcat 7.0.54.

**Issue:**

When we added `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` into our main `@JavaConfig`, we experience the following exception:

> Unresolvable circular reference.

Which fails every `@Autowired` attempt on a long list of beans.

**Tried:**

- Removed the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation which autowires everything correctly but our @Aspect never gets invoked.
- Added the CGLIB support in the annotation by declaring
  `proxytargetclass=true` to no avail.
- We've tried following this documentation directly from Spring: [@EnableAspectJAutoProxy Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html)

This seems to be an issue with AspectJ's proxy mechanism dealing with autowired dependencies.

Why does this occur when we add the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`?

Our Java Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ={"com.company.product.persistence.repository"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableSwagger
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@PropertySource({"classpath:hibernate.properties",
                 "classpath:auth.properties",
                 "classpath:mail.properties",
                 "classpath:locations.properties"
                })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company.product"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    //Bean declarations here.
    //Note: All services/repos/controllers are annotation based.
}
```

Aspect implementation:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class PostMessageAspect {

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @After("execution(*com.company.product.persistence.serviceImpl.event.eventServiceImpl.methodCall(..))")
    public void postMessageRun(final JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        logger.info("CALLED AFTER METHOD");
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Managed to get AOP/AspectJ working perfectly fine on one dev machine only requiring a minor change to our Spring Security config. We are both using Intellij, openJDK 1.7.0_65 on Ubuntu 14.0.4 running on default instances of Tomcat 7.0.56. On the other machine running the same software stack, gets the following.

**Stack Trace:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dispatchingMessageController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.apx.efm.persistence.service.event.DispatchingEventService com.apx.efm.controllers.message.DispatchingMessageController.dispatchingEventService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dispatchingEventServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.apx.efm.persistence.service.building.BuildingAd dressesService com.apx.efm.persistence.serviceImpl.event.DispatchingEventServiceImpl.buildingAddressesService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'buildingAddressServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.apx.efm.persistence.service.building.BuildingService com.apx.efm.persistence.serviceImpl.building.BuildingAddressServiceImpl.buildingService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'buildingServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.apx.efm.persistence.service.building.BuildingAddressesService com.apx.efm.persistence.serviceImpl.building.BuildingServiceImpl.buildingAddressesService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor]: Factory method 'methodSecurityInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.apx.efm.persistence.service.user.EfmUserService com.apx.efm.application.config.SecurityConfig.efmUserService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'efmUserServiceImpl' defined in file [/home/apxdev4/Development/GitRepositories/efim-restful-web-service/target/EFIM/WEB-INF/classes/com/apx/efm/persistence/serviceImpl/user/EfmUserServiceImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Comment: Did you invoke the aspectj compiler when building your deployable?

Comment: @Hannes We followed this [spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html), under section: **9.2.1 Enabling AspectJ Support**.

Comment: What are the package names for the two classes you posted? And have you omitted any injected components inside your aspect?

Comment: @kriegaex The aspect component has nothing ommited. Anything data is under package persistence.* (IE: persistence.[repository, service, serviceImpl, entity]. Not sure how that is relevant. Note that the package names have been edited due to privacy.

Comment: I mean the package names for the aspect and the configuration class. You have a circular reference, such as component A depending on B, B on C, C on A. Privacy is nice, but we need some way to reproduce the problem. Otherwise you need to do it alone.

Comment: @kriegaex WebConfig class is under com.company.product.application.config and the PostMessageAspect class is under com.company.product.aspect.

Comment: Looks like a configuration issue or the source code snapshots are somehow different. Do you configure your dependencies automatically, e.g. via Maven? Or is the other machine maybe missing a dependency like aopalliance.jar? Hard to tell.

Comment: @kriegaex We seemed to have solved the issue by forcing Spring Security to be configured after our main config. We tried using `@Order`, `@Import` with no luck, the trick seems to be to register the config classes explicitely in our context initializer (IE: ctx.register(WebConfig.class); //then security).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was entirely an issue with our Spring configuration. Our Spring Security configuration was trying to `@Autowired` beans while they were still in the middle of being processed by our main application configuration. We solved this by ensuring that Spring Security gets configured after the main `@Configuration`.

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    // Initialize web mvc
    appContext.setDisplayName("APP");
    appContext.register(WebConfig.class);
    appContext.register(SecurityConfig.class);

    // Rest omitted (listeners, dispatcher servlet, etc.)
}
```